# Parse Framework with Swift

Tags: parse-platform, swift, ios8

Has anyone tried using the Parse Framework with swift yet? As long as you add a bridge-file you can work with both swift and objective-c code.

Here is my query.. the 'objects' array returned from Parse has all my data properly, but the method is returning before setting the 'results' array to the 'objects' array, so i keep getting nothing back from the function. Perhaps Parse will need to receive an update to support swift, or did I possibly make a mistake somewhere? Thanks

```
   class func fetchAllCategories() -> NSArray {

        var results : NSArray = NSArray()

        var query : PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Category")
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({(NSArray objects, NSError error) in
            if (error != nil) {
                NSLog("error " + error.localizedDescription)
            }
            else {
                NSLog("objects %@", objects as NSArray)
                results = NSArray(array: objects)
            }
        })

        NSLog("results %@", results)

        return results
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with Swift. `query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` does the work in the background so it's going to finish much later, after the function returns.

Comment: Oh your right. I will fix it by just reloading the table view inside the block instead of calling a method. Thanks