# findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock block signature not correct

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to fetch a bunch of rows with this code

```swift
var query = PFQuery(className:"Test")
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (objects: NSArray?, error: NSError?) in

    // do something
}
```

But it doesn't compile, I get the following error:

> Cannot invoke 'findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock' with an argument list of type '((NSArray?, NSError?) -> _)'

In [the docs](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#//api/name/findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:) I find this:

> block: The block to execute. It should have the following argument signature:
>   ^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error)

Which seems to be pretty similar to me. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It should be PFObject not NSArray

Comment: That still gives the same error

Comment: have you find solution ?

Comment: yes :) its down below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the correct syntax in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24029510/3960377).  Nothing wrong with the arguments list or wrapping/unwrapping the objects; instead, the closure had to be passed as an argument to `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock`. It works when written like this:

```
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock( { (NSArray results, NSError error) in
    // do something
})
```

Answer (score 4):

I am having the same issue. Are you using swift1.2? if so, i think it has something to do with the unwrapping "!". try changing your "!" to "?"

Answer (score 2):

Try this -

```
(objects:[AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) in
```

Then cast your [AnyObject] to a [PFObject]

```
let myObjects = objects as? [PFObject]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
//code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's basically saying that the two question marks are no longer needed.

```
findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {(objects: NSArray?, error: NSError?)
```

Becomes

`findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {(objects: NSArray, error: NSError`)

If I am wrong, can someone correct me, but this is what I have noticed from Google etc.