# Parse Query in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, parse-platform, ios8

I am trying to query in swift using parse.com.

I am getting an error even though I copied the code from Parse.

The code is:

```
  var query = PFQuery(className:"GameScore")
    query.whereKey("playerName", equalTo:"Sean Plott")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject], error: NSError) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            // The find succeeded.
            println("Successfully retrieved \(objects.count) scores.")
            // Do something with the found objects
            if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                for object in objects {
                    println(object.objectId)
                }
            }
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            println("Error: \(error) \(error.userInfo!)")
        }
    }

}
```

`findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` is where the error is.

Comment: What is the error you're getting? What did you find when you read about the error?

Comment: Found this, may help http://stackoverflow.com/a/29587007/3900902

Answer (score 0):

replace `object` with `x`.

`object` most likely is a keyword, but you assign/use it as a variable.

I propose the following:

```
for x in objects { 
   println(x.objectId)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

3rd and 4th line should be as below:

```
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
```